# Addition of vectors c++. Cannot understand compilation error

Tags: c++, vector

Hi I am have written the following function for adding 2 vectors

```
vector<double> add(vector<double>& v1, vector<double>& v2 )

{  /*Do quick size check on vectors before proceeding*/

  vector<double> result(v1.size());
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i)
  {
    result[i]=v1[i]+v2[i];
  }

  return result;

}
```

Now I tried to add 3 vectors a,b,c all of same size in the following two ways

```
vector <double> sum1, sum2;

sum1=add(b,c);

sum2=add(a,sum1);
```

which worked

and

```
vector <double> sum;
sum=add(a,add(b,c));
```

which gave me the following compiler error

```
g++ -Wall simple.cpp 
simple.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
simple.cpp:45: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&’ from a temporary of type ‘std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >’
simple.cpp:16: error: in passing argument 2 of ‘std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > add(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&)’
```

Why did the second method not work?

Comment: you declared function taking *lvalue* reference `vector<double> add(vector<double>& v1, vector<double>& v2 )` while supplying *rvalue* temporary: `sum=add(a,add(b,c));` that's why the error. Temporaries can be bound to *const lvalues* or *[const] rvalues*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
vector<double> add(vector<double> v1, vector<double> v2 )
```

From the error message, I can say with 100% certaintly that this is not the function signature in your original code.

In your original code, you must be using this:

```
vector<double> add(vector<double> & v1, vector<double>  & v2 )
```

If so, then make it as:

```
vector<double> add(const vector<double> & v1, const vector<double>  & v2)
```

Now it should work just fine.

## Explanation:

The return value of `add()` is a temporary object, and a temporary object cannot be bound to *non-const* reference. That is why the compiler was giving error. It will give same error if you write this:

```
vector<double> & v = add(a,b); //error
```

However, if a temporary object can be bound to `const` reference. That is why I suggested you to make the parameter `const` reference.  That means, you can write this:

```
const vector<double> & v = add(a,b); //ok
```

Also, you can make the parameter non-const non-reference as well, that is, pass the arguments by *value*. But I would not recommend that, as it involves *unnecessary copies* of the vectors.

The best solution is this:

```
vector<double> add(const vector<double> & v1, const vector<double>  & v2)
```

---

## Getting familiar with operator+

You could also overload `operator+` for vector, as:

```
vector<double> operator + (const vector<double>& v1, const vector<double>& v2 )
{  
  /*Do quick size check on vectors before proceeding*/
  vector<double> result(v1.size());
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i)
  {
    result[i]=v1[i]+v2[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

If you overload this, then you can write this cool code:

```
vector<double> c = a + b;
vector<double> d = a + b + c;
vector<double> e = a + b + c + d;
//so on
```

Isn't it fun?

## Getting familiar with Standard algorithm..

As @Gene commented, you could use `std::transform` in the function as:

```
vector<double> operator+(const vector<double>& v1, const vector<double>& v2 )
{  
   vector<double> result;
   std::transform(v1.begin(),v1.end(),v2.begin(), 
                            std::back_inserter(result), std::plus<double>);
   return result;
}
```

Comment: yes. I used the second one and have made the edit. Why did the second method not work though. Isn't that passing by reference? Of course as you say without the `&` the code works

Comment: @GaurishTelang: I explained that in my answer.

Comment: @GaurishTelang: Did you see the `operator+`? I just added it.

Comment: the best solution is to use one liner: `std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), std::back_inserter(result), std::plus<double>)` instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @GeneBushuyev: Included your suggestion in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Eliminating the `add()` function and substituting calls to it by `v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end())` would be a much more efficient solution.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: I think you didn't understand the question. He is not adding contents from one vector to another. He is adding the contents themselves.

Comment: Ok, two lines of code then. `std::vector<double> r(v1); r.insert(r.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());`

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Does that add the contents? Did you see what OP is doing in his code?

Comment: ... possibly constructing with a size instead.

Comment: oh. sorry, i thought he meant appending by that. read too fast. :-S

Comment: @wilhelmtell: And did you notice this : `result[i] = v1[i] + v2[i]` in his code?

Comment: Thank you for that information about operator overloading Nawaz! It is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<double> add(vector<double>& v1, vector<double>& v2 )
```

Because we expect the function to modify its arguments, we cannot call the function with just any expression. Instead we must pass an lvalue argument to a reference parameter. An lvalue is a value that denotes a nontemporary object.

```
sum=add(a,add(b,c));
```

The preceding call to add tries to pass a temporary object.